# Omni channel for sales cloud

Tags: lightning, community, liveagent, omnichannel, chat

I have tried the omni channel for chatting on the service cloud.

Can we use the omni channel for chatting on the Sales cloud?

If yes, then how to configure it?

Also, what is the cost for using the omni channel in the salesforce?

Is there any alternative solution in sales cloud for chatting? I dont want any third party apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Omni Channel for Sales cloud for Leads, Order, Custom Objects, But not for Opportunities. [Supported Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=service_presence_supported_objects.htm&type=5), Though you can work around using a shadow custom object.

Each sales cloud user also needs to have a service cloud license. You account executive should be able to get a discount. As far as I can see, the benefit outweighs the cost.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use the omni channel for chatting on the Sales cloud?

As far as I'm aware, and with our functional setup of this feature. Omni Channel only functions for users Service Cloud licences

> If yes, then how to configure it?

Please see the below link

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=service_presence_intro.htm&type=5

> Also, what is the cost for using the omni channel in the salesforce?

You'll have to get in contact with your Account Exec to discuss prices, they vary in terms of user numbers and discounts you can negotiate

Comment: Is here any alternative solution in sales cloud for chatting? I don't want any third party apps.

Comment: @Ajinkyasd Do you mean with customers externally or internally between employees?

Comment: Both... Internal as well as external users should be able to chat.